# How to pass mutliple forms to FormData() Jquery ajax

Tags: html, jquery, form-data

i am working on a contact form which has multiple form data with file types and other input types also, i tried using serialize() but it only sends data other than file type. after searching on the internet found formdata(). it is perfectly working with one form but i want to send data at once of all 3 forms to my send.php file

```
            var dataString = new FormData();
            
            dataString.append('step1', $('#step1').get(0));
            dataString.append('step2', $('#step2').get(0));
            dataString.append('step32', $('#step3').get(0));


            console.log(dataString);
            
            // send form to send.php
            $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                    url: "form handling/send.php",
                    data: dataString,
                      processData: false,
                     contentType: false,
                     success: function(data,status) {


                           $("#sub").html("Sent!");
                        // window.location = 'form handling/send.php';
                        
                     },
                     error: function(data, status)
                     {
                        $("#sub").html("failed!");
                     }
                  });
```

tried the above but no luck
the steps1, step2, step3 are forms id

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The FormData constructor can be used with a form as argument to get the form data for this form.
So you can use it on all your steps forms, then combine all the forms data into one FormData that you will use instead of dataString in your actual code.

```
const formData1 = new FormData(document.querySelector('#step1'));
const formData2 = new FormData(document.querySelector('#step2'));
const formData3 = new FormData(document.querySelector('#step3'));
// combine all formData into allFormsData
const allFormsData = new FormData();
for (const [key, value] of [...formData1.entries(), ...formData2.entries(), ...formData3.entries()]) {
    allFormsData.append(key, value)
}
// then send form to send.php
$.ajax({
    // ...
    data: allFormsData
    // ...
})
```

Comment: can u explain it more please kinda new to these